# Using Macros to generate graph parameters SAS

Tags: graph, sas

I am attempting to automate a graph process using SAS macros.  Since this will be used for several different subsets, the axes of the graph must be adjusted accordingly.  I haver tried a few different ways and feel that I'm going the wrong way down the rabbit hole.

Here is my dataset.

```
data want;
    input A B C D;
cards;
100 5   6   1
200 5   5   2
150 5.5 5.5 3
457 4.2 6.2 4
500 3.7 7.0 5
525 3.5 7.2 6
;
run;
```

What I want is a graph that has the following axis specs:
x-axis from min(D) to max(D) by some reasonable increment
left-axis from min(A) to max(A)
right-axis from min (B,C) to max(B,C)

Here is my latest attempt:

```
proc sql;
    select  roundz((max(A)+100), 100),
        roundz(min(A), 100),
        (&maxA.-&minA.)/10,
        roundz(max(B, C)+1, 1),
        roundz(min(B, C), 1), 
        (&maxBC.-&minBC.)/10, 
        roundz(max(D), 1), 
        roundz(min(D), 1),
        (&maxD.-&minD.+1)/3
        into :maxA, :minA, :Ainc,
            :maxBC, :minBC, :BCinc,
            :maxD, :minD, :Dinc
    from want;
run;


goptions reset=all ftext=SWISS htext=2.5 ;
axis1 order=(&minA to &maxA by &Ainc) minor=none label=(angle=90 'A label' ) offset=(1) ;
axis2 order=(&minBC to &maxBC by &BCinc) minor=(number=1) label=(angle=90 'BC Label') offset=(1);
axis3 order=(&minD to &maxD by &Dinc) minor=(number=2) label=('D') offset=(1) ;
symbol1 color=black i=join value=circle height=2 width=2 ;
symbol2 color=black i=join value=square height=2 width=2 ;
symbol3 color=black i=join value=triangle height=2 width=2 ;
legend1 label=none mode=reserve position=(top center outside) value=('Label here' ) shape=symbol(5,1) ;
legend2 label=none mode=reserve position=(top center outside) value=('label 1' 'label 2') shape=symbol(3,1) ;


proc gplot data=want;
    plot A*D=1 /overlay legend=legend1 vaxis=axis1 haxis=axis3 ;
    plot2 B*D=2 &var_C*D=3 /overlay legend=legend2 vaxis=axis2 ;
run ;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Even if that means a completely different way of doing it (though I'd also be interested to see where I am going wrong here).

Thanks, Pyll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is sort-of writing a macro without writing a macro.  Write the macro and this is easier.  Also, if you're going to have the INCs always be 1/10ths, put that in let statements (although if they might vary in their conception, then leave them as parameters).

```
%macro graph_me(minA=,maxA=, minBC=,maxBC=, minD=, maxD=);
 %let incA = %sysevalf((&maxA.-&minA.)/10); *same for incD and incBC;
 goptions reset=all ftext=SWISS htext=2.5 ;
 axis1 order=(&minA to &maxA by &incA) minor=none label=(angle=90 'A label' ) offset=(1) ;
 axis2 order=(&minBC to &maxBC by &incBC) minor=(number=1) label=(angle=90 'BC Label')  offset=(1); 
 axis3 order=(&minD to &maxD by &incD) minor=(number=2) label=('D') offset=(1) ;
 symbol1 color=black i=join value=circle height=2 width=2 ;
 symbol2 color=black i=join value=square height=2 width=2 ;
 symbol3 color=black i=join value=triangle height=2 width=2 ;
 legend1 label=none mode=reserve position=(top center outside) value=('Label here' )  shape=symbol(5,1) ; 
 legend2 label=none mode=reserve position=(top center outside) value=('label 1' 'label 2') shape=symbol(3,1) ;
%mend graph_me;
```

Now write your SQL call to grab those parameters into the macro call itself.

```
proc sql NOPRINT;
    select 
        cats('%graph_me(minA=',roundz(min(A), 100),
        ',maxA=', roundz((max(A)+100), 100),        
        ... etc. ...
       into :mcall
    from want;
quit;
```

This gives you the advantage that you may be able to generate multiple calls if you, for example, want to do this grouped by some variable (having one graph per variable value).

Answer (score 1):

2 things in the sql: 
you cannot use the macros you are creating and you need just one value, when doing `max(B,C)` you are creating as many values as there are obs in the dataset, you need another `max`.
I cannot check the sas graph part as I do not have it, but

```
proc sql NOPRINT;
    select  roundz((max(A)+100), 100)  as maxA,
        roundz(min(A), 100) as minA,
        ((calculated maxA)-(calculated minA))/10,
        roundz(max(max(B, C))+1, 1) as maxBC,
        roundz(min(min(B, C)), 1) as minBC,
        ((calculated maxBC)-(calculated minBC))/10, 
        roundz(max(D), 1) as maxD, 
        roundz(min(D), 1) as minD,
        ((calculated maxD)-(calculated minD)+1)/3
        into :maxA, :minA, :Ainc,
            :maxBC, :minBC, :BCinc,
            :maxD, :minD, :Dinc
    from want;
quit;
```